# How Do I Make A Checkbox Checked By Default?

Tags: php

Using PHP and sessions, how can I check a checkbox the first time the page is loaded?

Here is a minimal sample of my code:

**index.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = $_POST['foo'];
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
  <form method='POST'>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkFoo" name="foo" <?php echo (isset($_POST['foo']) && $_POST['foo'] === 'on') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
    <label for="checkFoo">checkbox</label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <?php include 'print.php'; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**print.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['foo'].' ';
?>
```

Apart from the default value, this code works exactly as I intend:

- When the user checks the checkbox and clicks submit, it prints 'on'
- When the user unchecks the checkbox and clicks submit, it prints nothing
- Clicking the submit button does not change the value of the checkbox

How can I change the default (startup) value of the checkbox to 'on', without changing the above behavior?

**Edit**:  With the accepted answer, everything was working as I expected, except on the first load of the page - the checkbox was selected but the value printed out in code was null.  I got it working with this:

**index.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['submit'] = $_POST['submit'] ?? null;
$_SESSION['foo'] = $_POST['foo'] ?? '';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
  <form method='POST'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkFoo" value="on" name="foo" <?php echo ((!isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SESSION['foo'] != 'off') || ($_SESSION['foo'] === 'on')) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>

    <label for="checkFoo">checkbox</label>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <?php include 'print.php'; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**print.php**:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();
$foo = ((!isset($_SESSION['submit']) && $_SESSION['foo'] != 'off') || ($_SESSION['foo'] === 'on')) ? true : false;
echo 'foo='.$foo.'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: Maybe just by reversing the condition. checked by default, and unchecked if foo equals off.

Comment: Foo is never euqal to 'off', it's either 'on' or '' (null).  When I set checked by default, then the box gets set to checked every time the user clicks submit, even if the user unchecks the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the page will be first loaded, the `$_POST['submit']` would not be set as the page would be accessed using a `GET` Request.

So Modify the files:
`index.php`

```php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = $_POST['foo'] ?? '';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
  <form method='POST'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkFoo" value="on" name="foo" <?php echo ((!isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SESSION['foo'] != 'off') || ($_SESSION['foo'] === 'on')) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>

    <label for="checkFoo">checkbox</label>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <?php include 'print.php'; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

`print.php`

```php
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
if(isset($_SESSION['foo'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['foo'].' ';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little verbose, but it's good practice to use a default value, then check if something exists before setting a variable to it.

Something like this should work.

```php
<?php
session_start();
// default value is on
$foo = "on";

// if session has a value, use it instead
if(isset($_SESSION["foo"])){
    $foo = $_SESSION["foo"];
}


// if post has a value, use it instead and set the session value
if(isset($_POST["foo"])){
    $foo = $_POST["foo"];
    $_SESSION["foo"] = $_POST["foo"];
}

$checked = $foo === "on";
```

This can be simplified in newer PHP versions (7+)

```php
<?php
session_start();
$foo = $_POST["foo"] ?? $_SESSION["foo"] ?? "on";
if(isset($_POST["foo"])){
    $_SESSION["foo"] = $foo;
}
```

Comment: With this solution, at startup, the value of the session variable is set to 'on', but the checkbox is not checked.  Thereafter, every time you hit submit, the session variable has a value of 'on', regardless of whether or not the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Add a `hidden` input field before the checkbox with the value "off" with the same name. That's a workaround. Alternatively just change the initial value of `$foo` to `$foo === ""` and change the `$checked` logic to `$checked = $foo === "on" || $foo  === ""`

Comment: You'll keep running into the same issue unless you specify another default value other than an empty string (since that's what is posted with the empty checkbox).

Comment: The code that you posted did not work for reasons I described.  The accepted answer fixed the problem, with one glitch which I fixed in the edit to my original post.

Comment: In the "simplified" version, it does in fact set the session variable to "on", but not in the original one. It only sets the session variable when they post field exists. Aside from that, the code is much more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: I tested your 'simplified' version on the day you posted it and, as I said then, the result is that, every time you hit sumbit, the session variable has a value of 'on', regardless of whether or not the checkbox is checked.

Comment: That's what I'm saying - the simplified version does that - the full one doesn't. I've made a slight adjustment which changes the behaviour to only update the session variable if post was set. That's all it takes to "fix" it.